# Simple C++ tokenizer

Tags: c++, tokenize

I'm writing a program for a challenge on HackerRank, and I need to parse HRML, a markup language similar to HTML:

```
<tag1 value = "Hello World"></tag1>
```

As a part of the program I have a function which is supposed to fill a vector of strings with the string tokens. It works fine with the tags, but I also need to tokenize queries, which are in the following format:

```
tag1.tag2.tag3~attribute_name
```

The function behaves like the string iterator stops advancing after it encounters a tilde.
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void tokenize_string(vector<string>& vector, string str)
{
    string current_token;

    for (auto i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); i++)
    {

        if (isalnum(*i))
        {
            current_token += *i;
        }
        else
        {
            //We extracted a token
            vector.push_back(current_token);
            current_token = "";
        }
    }

    //Remove empty strings that the previous loop placed into the vector
    for (auto i = vector.begin(); i != vector.end(); i++)
    {
         if (*i == "")
        {
            vector.erase(i);
            i = vector.begin();
        }
    }
} 
int main()
{
    //A simple test
    vector<string> tag_tokens;
    vector<string> query_tokens;

    tokenize_string(tag_tokens, "<tag1 name=\"Hello\">");
    tokenize_string(query_tokens, "tag1.tag2.tag3~name");

    for (auto it = tag_tokens.begin(); it != tag_tokens.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
    for (auto it = query_tokens.begin(); it != query_tokens.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please clarify this sentence "The function behaves like the string iterator stops advancing after it encounters a tilde."  We need to know exactly what you expected and what actually happened.

Comment: I ran it through a debugger, and figured out the problem. The thing is, the name of the attribute never gets pushed into the vector because there is no non alphanumeric sign after the attribute name. Thanks!

Comment: @ravenspoint I expected the function to push all alphanumeric tokens into the vector(separated by any non alphanumeric sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not considering the last token after reaching the end of the input string
`i != str.end()`.
Add             `vector.push_back(current_token);` after for loop as below to consider last token.

```
void tokenize_string(vector<string>& vector, string str)
{
    string current_token;

    for (auto i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); i++)
    {

        if (isalnum(*i))
        {
            current_token += *i;
        }
        else
        {
            //We extracted a token
            vector.push_back(current_token);
            current_token = "";
        }
    }
                vector.push_back(current_token);   ///-------->pushes last token

    //Remove empty strings that the previous loop placed into the vector
    for (auto i = vector.begin(); i != vector.end(); i++)
    {
         if (*i == "")
        {
            vector.erase(i);
            i = vector.begin();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way to do this that needs less lines of code:

```
void tokenize_string(
    std::vector< std::string >& output,
    const std::string& csv,
    const string& delimiters )
{
    for( char del : delimiters ) {
      std::stringstream sst(csv);
      std::string a;
      while( getline( sst, a, del) )
        output.push_back(a);
   }
}
```

Comment: I need more than one delimiter (characters < , > , = , ~, dot, and space).

Comment: The extension for multiple delimiters is fairly obvious, see edited code.